# Where should I put my API key references and env files in a Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I know I shouldn't hardcode my api keys and my mongo URL directly in my app.js file. Where should I put them? Should I just put them in a file called config.js and then export that as a module, then require that in my app.js file? What's the best way to do so, so when I move to production I don't have to change anything?

Answer (score 1):

- I'd go with **[config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config)** module. It's a simple lib which loads the proper `json` file according with your **`NODE_ENV`** value.
  For example, if you specify `NODE_ENV=development npm start` it'll load `development.json` and so on.
- Another possibility: define a folder in your system outside your project folder and load your `json` files from there. For example, if you define `/etc/opt/my-project-configs/` you would create that folder in your local system and in your *pre/pro* servers. Your code wouldn't know which environment is actually running but will load the proper config file.

Comment: This makes since, but I assume I should put my config file in my .gitignore file. Once if go from github to heroku, what will heroku do when it sees require("config.js"), this file, not the module?

Answer (score 1):

In your `config.js` file you can do something like

```
module.exports = {
  accessKeyId: process.env.SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID
}
```

now put your keys in environmemt by using following command on terminal

```
export env.SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID='yourSecretKey'
```

now to use the setting do

```
var config = require('relativ/path/to/config.js');
someFunction(config.accessKeyId);
```

hope it helps :)